# Decreased Paycheck

Tags: united-states, taxes, income

My Feb. 2018 paycheck decreased, while it seems the rest of the nation is enjoying an increase. My boss said I must fall into that “10%”. I earn an average salary. Can someone help me understand the decrease?

Comment: Decrease in what line item and compared to what? total, hourly rate, taxes, take home. Also what country are you in?

Comment: I'm on salary, but my three 2018 paychecks have fluctuated (sometime higher, sometimes lower).  The first thing I did was compare the pay stubs, which detail all deductions (taxes, benefits, etc).  That told me exactly what's changed.

Comment: more details are needed.

Comment: Perhaps you might explain how you are getting a February paycheck when it's only the 3rd of the month?

Comment: Payday for some people is Friday February 2nd. From the IRS "Employers should implement the 2018 withholding tables as soon as possible, but not later than February 15, 2018. "

Comment: @jamesqf "*Perhaps you might explain how you are getting a February paycheck when it's only the 3rd of the month?*" easy peasy if you're paid bi-weekly and the last check was January 18th (my wife's) or the 19th (mine).

Comment: @RonJohn: But that would be a paycheck for the last two weeks of January.  At most it'd include two days of February, and then only if you have an employer who does things ahead of time.

Comment: @jamesqf my paycheck arrived on **and is dated** 02-Feb-2018.  That makes it -- by definition -- a February paycheck.  Just as the paycheck that arrived on 05-Jan-2018 was a January paycheck.

Comment: @RonJohn: Perhaps the question is better suited to the ELU site, but to me, a February paycheck means payment for work I did in February, even if it doesn't arrive until April.  (Which does sometimes happen when you're self-employed :-()

Comment: @jamesqf ELU?  Anyway, consider the check I got on 05-Jan: it's for hours worked in December 2017, but the IRS considers it 2018 money, because that's when I got it.  The pay**check** is from the **date on the check**.

Comment: @RonJohn: ELU = English Language & Usage.

Answer (score 1):

Three things are happening:

1. In February 2018 the new withholding tax tables are being used. Normally this would have happened in January, and would have not been very noticeable. In a typical year the tables change because the borders of the brackets are index to inflation. But this year the actual rates have changed, so that make the shift more noticeable.
2. The standard deduction changed. Many people are impacted by that change.
3. The personal exemption was eliminated and the child tax credit was modified. There is also a new tax credit for non-child dependents.

For most people #1 will lower their withholding and increase their pay check.

The problem is that #2 and #3 mean that you should adjust your W-4 using the new tools due to be released by the end of February 2018.

The best thing is to wait until the new tools are ready. Then use them to see if you need to adjust your W-4. Also keep in mind that some states may also be making changes to their version of the W-4, and may adjust their withholding rules.

Comment: And deductions, too.  My LTD has been different every time: deducted, not deducted, deducted 2x.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the net pay is pretty useless for a comparison.

You need to check in more detail on all deductions: did you pay more for *health insurance* (probably yes), did you pay more for *dental insurance*, did you pay more for *eye insurance*, did your 401k contributions change, etc.

**The only deduction the new laws changed are *federal taxes***, so compare a paycheck from 2017 with one from 2018, and see if your federal taxes changed. Note that they would also go up if you got a raise, which many companies tack on in January.